# How can I display 'Delete Confirm Dialog' with bootstrap's modal? not like browser's default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I was looking at this page( http://lesseverything.com/blog/archives/2012/07/18/customizing-confirmation-dialog-in-rails/ ) It shows some codes in there but I don't understand how I can implement it to my app.

I use Rails3.2, Bootstrap.css and JQuery.
Can someone tell me what exactly I have to do to display 'Delete Confirm Dialog' with bootstrap's modal?

UPDATE:

**assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require autocomplete-rails
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[The blog entry](http://lesseverything.com/blog/archives/2012/07/18/customizing-confirmation-dialog-in-rails/) uses coffeescript. Say you are using the `:confirm` option in your rails form, then you need to override the default action in Rails, by putting the following code in the `<controller>.js.coffee` file in your assets pipeline (`app/assets/javascript`):

```
$.rails.allowAction = (link) ->
  return true unless link.attr('data-confirm')
  $.rails.showConfirmDialog(link) # look bellow for implementations
  false # always stops the action since code runs asynchronously

$.rails.confirmed = (link) ->
  link.removeAttr('data-confirm')
  link.trigger('click.rails')

$.rails.showConfirmDialog = (link) ->
  message = link.attr 'data-confirm'
  html = """
         <div class="modal" id="confirmationDialog">
           <div class="modal-header">
             <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
             <h3>#{message}</h3>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
             <p>Are you sure you want to delete?</p>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
             <a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Cancel</a>
             <a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary confirm">OK</a>
           </div>
         </div>
         """
  $(html).modal()
  $('#confirmationDialog .confirm').on 'click', -> $.rails.confirmed(link)
```

You can then use links like this in your view and they should display the Bootstrap modal instead of the standard browser pop-up:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', item, :method => :delete, :confirm=>'Are you sure?' %>
```

**UPDATE**

This works for me using the `:remote => true` option as well.

So if I have something like the following in my index.html.erb view:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Content</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr id="<%= post.id %>">
    <td><%= post.name %></td>
    <td><%= post.title %></td>
    <td><%= post.content %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, :remote => true, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

And the destroy action in the controller has `format.js` in the respond_to:

```
  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

And this in the destroy.js.erb:

```
$("tr#<%= @post.id %>").fadeOut();
```

Then it all works. When you click the `Destroy` link, the Bootstrap confirmation dialog pops up, and when you click OK, the row fades out and has been destroyed on the server.

Comment: Thank you so much with detailed explanation. I copied the first code to `communities.js.coffee`, and 2nd code to `/views/communities/index.html.erb`. However, modal won't pop up. The default dialog still pops up. Do you know why?

Comment: To check: I assume you have Bootstrap JavaScript added to Rails (i.e. not just CSS) - `bootstrap.min.js` or `bootstrap.js` should be in your asset path as well? What errors show up in your JavaScript console when you load the page or click Delete?

Comment: Thanks. I have `bootstrap.js.coffee`, and `rails.js` in **assets/javascripts**, and `bootstrap.css.erb` in **assets/stylesheets**. I updated my Question. Please check

Comment: It doesn't even anything unless I hit delete button in default dialog. When I click on the delete link, dialog pops up but no error on web console.

Comment: Have you included the `jquery-rails` gem in your Gemfile? If so, can you also add `//= require jquery_ujs` *before* the `require_tree` statement and see if that helps?

Comment: I have a question. It shouldn't work if I enable `:remote => true?` on link_to